# Are all sets in sigma-algebra measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

In the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) article it says:

> the collection of those subsets for which a given measure is defined
>   is necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra.

Fine, but is the opposite true? Do we know for sure that all sets of sigma algebra are measurable? If the answer is **no**, then is it the reason why Borel sigma algebra is so widely used in probability theory?

Comment: The Borel sigma algebra is useful when discussing measurable functions, since we would like continuous functions to be measurable. As for your first question, how do you define a measurable set? The definition implies the existence of a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Your question is not clear: what $\sigma$-algebra and what measure are you talking about?

Comment: @Crostul  
I'm talking about any sigma algebra - whether it's true that all elements (i.e. sets) of any sigma algebra are measurable.

Comment: A set $A$ is not loosely measurable. It is measurable *with respect to* some $\sigma$-algebra. When is this the case? Exactly when $A$ is an element of that $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Well, it depends on the measure and on the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @drhab _One would like to assign a size to every subset of X, but in many natural settings, this is not possible. [...] For this reason, one considers instead a smaller collection of privileged subsets of X. These subsets will be called the measurable sets. They are closed under operations that one would expect for measurable sets, that is, the complement of a measurable set is a measurable set and the countable union of measurable sets is a measurable set. Non-empty collections of sets with these properties are called σ-algebras._ - so how should I understand this?

Comment: How do I know that a sigma algebra doesn't contain Vitaly set, which isn't measurable?

Comment: The Vitali set is not *Lebesgue measurable*, so is not an element of the $\sigma$-algebra consisting of *Lebesgue measurable* sets. Again you cannot loosely say: this set is (not) measurable. If $V$ is the Vitali set then $\{\varnothing,V,V^c,\mathbb R\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $V$ is measurable with respect to that $\sigma$-algebra. Simply because it is an element of it.

Comment: @drhab So the statement 'this set is measurable' is meaningless? I've seen it has been used in many places, like here: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set : _they require a lot of formalism to prove that sets are measurable_ - with respect to what sigma algebra? However, in another article, I've seen a definition that a set is measurable if its outer and inner measures are equal.

Comment: The statement is indeed meaningless if context lacks. Every [outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure) induces a $\sigma$-algebra (see the answer of @Etienne) and the restriction of the outer measure to this $\sigma$-algebra is a measure. In special case a set belongs to that $\sigma$-algebra if it has equal outer an inner measure. Proving that a set is not measurable (requiring a lot of formalism) is the same as proving that it is not an element of the $\sigma$-algebra **that is involved**. Most cases deal with Borel- or Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one answer, which may answer the question as I understand it (but perhaps I do not understand the question correctly).

Start with a measure $\mu$ defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$. Then define the outer measure $\mu^*$ associated with $\mu$, in the sense of Caratheodory. Once you have this outer measure, you can define the class $\mathcal A(\mu^*)$ of all $\mu^*$-measurable sets (still in the sense of Caratheodory).

Then, it is part of the Caratheodory extension theorem that $\mathcal A\subseteq \mathcal A(\mu^*)$. So, in this sense, the answer to the question is "Yes".

On the other hand, it is not necessarily tru that all measurable sets belong to the original $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$...

Answer (score 3):

I think you possibly miss an concept about measurable. **A set $a$ in an sigama-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is called a $\mathcal{A}$-measurable set.**

So, measurable is not an general idea. It must correspond to a sigama-algebra. Measurable is given with respect to a given sigama-algebra. Therefore, you cannot generally say that a set is measurable without saying which sigma -algebra it belongs to.

Back to your question, the correct question should be "Are all sets in sigma-algebra $\mathcal{A}_1$ $\mathcal{A}_1$-measurable?". The answer is Yes. The problem can also be "Are all sets in sigma-algebra $\mathcal{A}_1$ $\mathcal{A}_2$-measurable?". The answer is Yes if the set is in $\mathcal{A}_2$ too. The answer is No if the set is not in $\mathcal{A}_2$.

Answer (score 0):

The term “measurable” is defined only in relation to a given measure. For example, in the counting measure, all sets are measurable (the finite sets have as measure the number of elements, the infinite sets have measure $\infty$). In the Lebesgue measure, there are unmeasurable sets (assuming the axiom of choice).

If you mean “there exists a measure in which every set is measurable” then yes, every member of a given sigma algebra is measurable for some measure. In particular, since all sets are measurable in the counting measure, this in particular is true for all the sets in the given sigma algebra.

Note also that all subsets of a set form a sigma algebra. Therefore for any measure that has unmeasurable sets, there exists a sigma algebra in which not all sets are measurable, namely the sigma algebra of all subsets.

Therefore if you mean “for a given arbitrary measure, are the sets in every sigma algebra measurable” the answer is no: Since every set is member of the sigma algebra of all subsets, any measure with unmeasurable sets is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set $X$ and any $\sigma$-algebra (denoted $\mathcal{P}_\sigma\left(X\right)$) of $X$, is there always an outer measure $\mu^*$ on $X$ (which, by definition, applies to all subsets of $X$ including $\mathcal{P}_\sigma\left(X\right)$), so that $\mathcal{P}_\sigma\left(X\right)$ is the set of all $\mu^*$-measurable subsets of $X$?

At this point, if the answer is yes, we don't assume that this outer measure is unique. In other words, if the answer is yes, we should presume that there are many such outer measures. Therefore, to find the condition of the positive answer to this question means to at least raise one example.

Since the answer asks for something not necessarily exist for a given $\sigma$-algebra, we must start with something always exist for any $\sigma$-algebra. What we do is direct *define* such a thing on $\sigma$-algebra, and better it can be related in some way to outer measure.

Since we know that 1) Given an outer measure $\mu^*$ on $X$, the set of all $\mu^*$-measurable subsets of $X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of $X$; and 2) Any outer measure $\mu^*$ is countably additive on pair-wise disjoint $\mu^*$-measurable sets. So, what we try to define for a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{P}_\sigma\left(X\right)$ of a set $X$ is an outer measure $\mu^*$ that is countably additive on pair-wise disjoint elements of $\mathcal{P}_\sigma\left(X\right)$. We call the latter a measure.

The next several steps to reach the answer to the original question is similarly written in most textbooks. Namely, check if the measure space is both $\sigma$-finite and complete. If so, extent the measure $\mu$ to an outer measure $\mu^*$ in the sense of Caratheodory and we get one what the question asked for. If not so, try another measure. There are many examples of general measure spaces that are both $\sigma$-finite and complete.

Therefore, the answer to the question is conditionally yes: if on this $\sigma$-algebra there exists a measure by which the measure space is $\sigma$-finite and complete then yes.

Of course, this only converts the question into a next one: is there always a measure on any $\sigma$-algebra of a set that is $\sigma$-finite and complete? Fact: the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is not complete with respect to any $\sigma$-finite measure.